# Not POSTing Without Graphics

Tags: bios, motherboard, post

I have a homelab with an ROG STRIX B760-I Gaming Wifi motherboard ([bios manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1700/ROG_STRIX_B760-I_GAMING_WIFI/E21631_ROG_STRIX_B760_series_BIOS_EM_WEB.pdf?model=ROG%20STRIX%20B760-I%20GAMING%20WIFI)), and upon changing the operating system it will no longer POST unless I have a graphics card.  When there is no graphics card plugged in, the white VGA POST error light is illuminated. I have also let it sit for 5-10 minutes hoping it would just be delayed, but no.

Prior to changing the operating system, it would POST and boot just fine. Is there some bios configuration that I can change to force the system to post without graphics? I have combed through the above bios manual to no avail. I'm mostly dumbfounded at how it ever worked in the first place. Is there some setting that may be enabled that would require graphics without explicitly saying so?

I realize that the majority of mobos require graphics to POST nowadays, but it was working before which gives me some hope that I'm missing something.

When I built it I figured I would save the $100 or so to get a cpu without graphics, which I am now regretting...

Comment: Check that you have Legacy PCI mode enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I don't know that there's a setting for that.  I tried changing my boot mode to legacy only, but then I was unable to select a boot drive (big surprise, right). The only noticeable difference I've been able to make was with the hardware prefetcher.  It stops posting significantly earlier with it disabled.